# why does kitchen faucet only work when dishwasher is running

Tags: kitchens, faucet

Kitchen faucet only works when the dishwasher is running. I tried cleaning the diswasher filter but made no difference. Any ideas?

Comment: `Kitchen faucet only works`  .... what does this actually mean?

Comment: Hot? Cold? Both?

Comment: Kitchen faucet just stopped working - both hot and cold, except when I turn the dishwasher on.

Comment: Typically a dishwasher and faucet will share one of the lines (hot in the US, cold in many other places) and the other line should be totally unaffected. If you upload a picture of the pipes going to the sink & dishwasher, that might help.

Comment: Some issue with spray nozzle diverter perhaps.